# Updating quantities in shopify using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify, variants

I'm trying to update attributes in shopify with the ruby API.  What I have right now is

```
product.variants = ShopifyAPI::Variant.new(:id => 753289571, :price => 12.00, :inventory_management => 'shopify', :inventory_quantity   => '100' )
```

Which I was expecting for the variant with id 753.... to update the price to 12.00 and the current quantity to 100.  When I do product.save it returns true. However, nothing has changed.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798708/how-to-efficiently-update-many-shopifyapiproduct-instances-using-shopifyapi-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not update the variant directly?

```
variant = ShopifyAPI::Variant.find(753289571)
variant.price = 12
variant.save
```